# How to load Nativescript chart properties from json file to xml file?

Tags: json, xml, nativescript

I want to load the Nativescript (RadCartesianChart) properties from external json file to my main xml file. How to call this RadCartesianChart property from an external json file?
The external json file should look like : 
    {
      "title":"chart",
      "chart-type":"Line",
      "x-axis":"month",
      "y-axis":"amount"
    }

This is my current xml file:

```
<Page 
loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" 
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
xmlns:sd="nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer"
xmlns:chart="nativescript-pro-ui/chart" 
>

<ActionBar title="MyApp" class="action-bar"/> 

<StackLayout class="home-panel">
      <Label textWrap="true" text="OVERVIEW" class="overview"/>
      <Label textWrap="true" text="Sales Report" class="graph-desc"/>
        <GridLayout class= "gLayout" rows="*"  height="800px" width="1300px">
            <chart:RadCartesianChart row="0">
                <chart:RadCartesianChart.series class="Line">
                    <chart:LineSeries items="{{ categoricalSource }}" categoryProperty="{{ categoryProperty }}" valueProperty="{{ valueProperty }}">
                        <chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
                            <chart:CategoricalAxis/>
                        </chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
                        <chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
                            <chart:LinearAxis/>
                        </chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
                    </chart:LineSeries>
                </chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart>
        </GridLayout>

        <GridLayout rows="*" xmlns:chart="nativescript-pro-ui/chart" height="800px" width="1300px">
        <chart:RadPieChart row="0" allowAnimation="true" row="0">
            <chart:RadPieChart.series>
                <chart:PieSeries selectionMode="DataPoint" expandRadius="0.4" outerRadiusFactor="0.7" items="{{ categoricalSource }}" valueProperty="Amount"
                 legendLabel="Department" />
            </chart:RadPieChart.series>
            <chart:RadPieChart.legend>
                <chart:RadLegendView position="Right" title="Dep" offsetOrigin="TopRight" width="110" enableSelection="true" />
            </chart:RadPieChart.legend>
        </chart:RadPieChart>
    </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding

In your js file add

```
// Either import your JSON here or...
var OptionsModel = require("./test.json");

// call GetString to get it from server or external source.
// and add it to OptionsModel.

// All the variables you wish to import in the xml add it to pageBinding as an object.
// then you can use {{'options or model or whatever name you give'.'value you want to access inside it'}}

page.bindingContext = {
  model: homeViewModel,
  options: OptionsModel
};
```

In your xml add

```
{{ model.categoricalSource }} or {{options.title}} to access values
```